# CSS-based mobile theming - JQM-style "linked lists" without using the full JQM framework

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

I need some mobile-specific styling, similar to what jquery mobile (and enyojs, sencha touch, etc.) offer.  In particular, I would like to use something similar to jqm's "[linked list](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/lists-ul.html)" style of navigation. However, I don't want to build a JQM site. I am building the site with backbone.js, and want to handle my own click events, routing and workflow--all I want is styling.  JQM and the others i listed seem to expect you to build a JQM "app" using their entire javascript framework.  For example, in JQM, the styles aren't applied directly to elements as classes, but rather, you provide `data-role="listview" data-theme="g"` and it will dynamically transform your lists into their styles.

Are there any open source css-based mobile themes out there that I can use to style my own `ul`'s similarly to a jqm linked list, and just handle the javascript event listeners and workflow myself? Or am I missing something and there is a way to just use JQM css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enyo's Onyx library includes a set of LESS files you can use to get the styling from Onyx.  Check out here:

https://github.com/enyojs/onyx/tree/master/css

Also, while not really mobile, you could always use bootstrap as a starting point if all you need is styling.

(Of course, Enyo is a great way to create an app so you shouldn't just dismiss it. ;) )

[oh wow, this question is old]

Comment: We ended up just having our front-end guy create the mobile styles for us, but this looks like a good answer!